# I can´t kill my python script in linux

Tags: python, linux, kill-process

I'm trying to kill my python process and always still there.

Also try using `sudo` and if I use top comand, the process is still there.

The python script was created by me, and no other process is continually calling.

```
ubuntu@ip-*******:~/Desktop/Servidor$ pkill python -e

python killed (pid 1284)

ubuntu@ip-*******:~/Desktop/Servidor$ pkill python -e

python killed (pid 1284)

ubuntu@ip-*******:~/Desktop/Servidor$ pkill python -e

python killed (pid 1284)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something you can use that is fairly brutal and will work for any rogue process is:

> ps ax | grep python | cut -c1-5 | xargs kill -9

which will probably need to be run as sudo.

Comment: @user2983041. You are welcome, I have used this on occasion with rogue psql and java processes that can't be stopped by normal means. Also, I see you are new to SO, so welcome, but if someone solves a problem for you, it is considered polite to accept the answer :D

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me and my python threading adventures gone awry.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
killall python or killall python2.7
```

Assuming python2.7 is what you are using.